# Terraform — how can I properly do a string interpolation in this code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-secrets-manager

My goal is to have this output:

```
DB_PASSWORD="secret1"
REDIS_PASSWORD="secret1"
```

But I can't make it work and I'm getting this error during `terraform plan`.

```
Error: Invalid index
...
        random_password.app_secrets is object with 2 attributes

  The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Could you please help me how to fix this issue? Here's how my code looks like.

```
locals {
  require_new_secrets = toset([
    "db",
    "redis"
  ])
}

resource "random_password" "app_secrets" {
  for_each = local.require_new_secrets
  length   = 16
  special  = false
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret" "app_secrets" {
  name_prefix             = "app-secrets-"
  recovery_window_in_days = 7
  tags                    = var.tags
}

resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "app_secrets" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.app_secrets.id
  secret_string = <<-EOF
    %{for x in local.require_new_secrets}
    ${upper("{x}_PASSWORD")}=${random_password.app_secrets["{x}"].result}
    %{endfor}
  EOF
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try with a `$` sign in front of `{x}`.

Comment: Terraform string interpolation uses `${}` not `{}`

Comment: That did the trick. I got confused with `$` position. Thank you guys!

Comment: @MarkoE Why not make it an answer for your solution? ;-)

Comment: :D the question asker should say something like `pls make an answer, I will accept it.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment, the interpolation syntax in Terraform requires you to add a `$` in front of any variable where substitution is required. For your code to work it is enough to add a `$` in front of both `{x}` placeholders:

```
resource "aws_secretsmanager_secret_version" "app_secrets" {
  secret_id     = aws_secretsmanager_secret.app_secrets.id
  secret_string = <<-EOF
    %{for x in local.require_new_secrets}
    ${upper("${x}_PASSWORD")}=${random_password.app_secrets["${x}"].result}
    %{endfor}
  EOF
}
```

More on interpolation syntax can be found in [1] and the example looks very similar to what you are trying to do.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/expressions/strings#directives